# How to add in another date column field codes so that update can work in the gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, date, gridview

I have this table called EVENT_ANNOUNCE that I used to display the data in the gridview. Currently, I can update EVENTTYPE, EVENTNAME and STARTDATE fine. But now I would like to add in another ENDDATE column code so that ENDDATE column can be updated. How do I add in the ENDDATE column code? as you can see from the 3rd screenshot, I got error when putting in. For the codes below are codes that are without the ENDDATE codes. And from the 3rd screenshot are the codes after I have add in the ENDDATE codes. Thanks

[image]
[image]

ERROR when I tried to put in the code for ENDDATE column field.
[image]

```
protected void grdEvent_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedRow = e.RowIndex;   //get selected row
        //  get product id from data key
        int id = (int)grdEvent.DataKeys[selectedRow].Value;

        //  get current grid view row
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdEvent.Rows[selectedRow];
        TextBox eventtype = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEventType");
        //  find text box for txtPrice
        TextBox eventname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEventName");
        TextBox startdate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtStartDate");
        TextBox enddate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEndDate");
        //  Remove $ sign
        string strEventType = eventtype.Text;
        string strEventName = eventname.Text;
        string strStartDate = startdate.Text;
        string strEndDate = enddate.Text;
        DateTime datStartDate;
        DateTime datEndDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strStartDate, new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" } ,
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datStartDate))
        {
            updateEventGridviewRecord(id, strEventType, strEventName, datStartDate);
        }


        else
        {
            lblError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "Invalid Date";
            lblSuccess.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void updateEventGridviewRecord(int id, string strEventType, string strEventName, DateTime datStartDate)
    {
        try
        {
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

            string strCommandText = "UPDATE EVENT_ANNOUNCE SET [EVENTTYPE]=@EVENTTYPE, [EVENTNAME]=@EVENTNAME, [STARTDATE]=@STARTDATE WHERE [ID]=@ID";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EVENTTYPE", strEventType);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EVENTNAME", strEventName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STARTDATE", datStartDate);
            myConnect.Open();

            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (result > 0)
            {
                lblSuccess.Visible = true;
                lblSuccess.Text = "Record updated!";
                lblError.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblSuccess.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Update fail";
                lblError.Visible = false;
            }

            myConnect.Close();


            //Cancel Edit Mode
            grdEvent.EditIndex = -1;
            bindEventGridView();
        }

        catch
        {
            lblError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "Please Enter Approximate data";
            lblSuccess.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to parse strStartDate  and strEndDate in one go. Just write a DateTime.TryParseExact FOR strEndDate SEPERATELY IN THE if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strStartDate, new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" } ,
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datStartDate)
    &&
    DateTime.TryParseExact(strEndDate, new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" } ,
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datEndDate)
   )
   {
       updateEventGridviewRecord(id, strEventType, strEventName, datStartDate);
   }
```